# Find the local extrema of the function $f(x)=x+\cos^2x$ in the interval $(0;2\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Find the local extrema of the function $$f(x)=x+\cos^2x$$ in the interval $(0;2\pi)$.

Let's start by taking the first derivative of the function, so $$f'(x)=1+2\cos x(-\sin x)=1-2\sin x\cos x=1-\sin 2x$$ The zeros of the first derivative are given by $$\sin 2x=1\iff2x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\iff x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ Only $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $x=\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ are in the desired interval.

So I decided to continue with the second derivative: $$f''(x)=0-2\cos{2x}=-2\cos{2x},$$ but $$f''\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=-2\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}=0$$ and $$f''\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}\right)=-2\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{2}=-2\cos\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{2}-2\pi\right)=-2\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}=0,$$ so this method is not applicable.

Now we are left to see what the signs of $f'(x)=1-\sin{2x}$ are in the intervals $\left(0;\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$, $\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4};\dfrac{5\pi}{4}\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{4};2\pi\right)$. How can one do that as I cannot intuitively say what they are?

Comment: $\sin 2x\le 1$, so $1-\sin 2x \ge 0$. Between those roots you have found, $1-\sin 2x >0$.

Comment: I wouldn’t check the sign of derivative on the entire domain but only around each of the two values of interest. The first derivative shows the function increasing so no extrema.

Comment: The function is strictly non-decreasing. There is no local extrema on an open interval for a strictly non-decreasing function (same can be said about a strictly non-increasing function). See this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pfnsj0ke9m.

If the interval were closed, then the local extrema would occur on the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: You can continue following your method with a higher order derivative test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test. Check the sign of the third derivative at these points.